# Exception with date formatter

Tags: jquery, sql, jsp, date

I've the below code in my jsp.

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*,java.text.*" %>
<%@include file="DBCon.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
try{

SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MM-yyy");
String a=request.getParameter("sid");
String b=request.getParameter("desc");
String c=request.getParameter("pubcode");
String d=request.getParameter("ProdType");
Date e=formater.parse(request.getParameter("DateRec"));
String f=request.getParameter("TimeRec");
String g=request.getParameter("Units");
Date h=formater.parse(request.getParameter("VWR"));
Date i=formater.parse(request.getParameter("AEDue"));
Date j=formater.parse(request.getParameter("AsByDate"));
String k=request.getParameter("SerID");
/* String sql="insert into Welcome_Page (SHIPMENT_ID_/_IDS, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, UNIT_COUNT, RECEIVED_DATE, RECEIVED_TIME, VWR_DUE_DATE, AE_DUE_DATE, ASSIGN_BY_DATE,SERIAL_NUMBER) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"; */
String sql="insert into Welcome_Page(SHIPMENT_ID_/_IDS, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, UNIT_COUNT, RECEIVED_DATE, RECEIVED_TIME, VWR_DUE_DATE, AE_DUE_DATE, ASSIGN_BY_DATE,SERIAL_NUMBER) values ("+a+", '"+c+"', "+b+", '"+d+"', "+g+", str_'"+e+"', '"+f+"', '"+h+"', '"+i+"', '"+j+"', "+k+")";
//ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
/* ps.setString(1,a);
ps.setString(2,c);
ps.setString(3,b);
ps.setString(4,d);
ps.setString(5,g);
ps.setString(6,e);
ps.setString(7,f);
ps.setString(8,h);
ps.setString(9,i);
ps.setString(10,j);
ps.setString(11,k);

 */
 out.println(sql);
 /* 
ps.executeQuery();
con.commit(); */
 }
catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
}
%>
</body>
</html>
```

here when i change `SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MM-yyy");` to `SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy:HH:mm:SS");`. I'm getting the below Exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "09-02-14"
```

If i leave it as it is i'm getting the below query.

```
insert into Welcome_Page(SHIPMENT_ID_/_IDS, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, UNIT_COUNT, RECEIVED_DATE, RECEIVED_TIME, VWR_DUE_DATE, AE_DUE_DATE, ASSIGN_BY_DATE,SERIAL_NUMBER) values (12, 'adfsf', 234234, 'Looseleaf - Update', 234234, str_'Fri Feb 09 00:00:00 IST 14', '43', 'Fri Mar 09 00:00:00 IST 14', 'Fri Aug 09 00:00:00 IST 15', 'Fri Nov 09 00:00:00 IST 14', 242)
```

here i actually have a jquery date picker in my main html file and i want to insert the date selected there to my database.

please let me know where i'm going wrong and also how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing, what is the format of date you are expecting and which one to parse.

Comment: Hi @ankur-singhal, i've parsed all the dates that are sent from the index.jsp, and while browsing, i came to know that the database will accept only the date format that it has in default, when i saw the default format in my database, it is `16-SEP-14`

Comment: what date you are trying to parse and also show how are you doing it ?

Comment: Hi All, sorry for the delayed reply, here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew7L1xs8/), here i'm parsing all the dates using `SimpleDateFormat`. please let me know if there are anymore queries. Thanks